# Can you add custom properties to child controls of your custom control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

If you add a TableLayoutPanel to a form, then add a control to one of its cells, the added control has extra properties in the Property Window (for example: Row, RowSpan, Column, ColumnSpan, Cell etc).

My question is, if you create your own custom control/component, is there a way to add properties to any existing control that becomes a child of your custom control, like the behavior of the TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Yes - those are called ExtenderProviders.  The ErrorProvider and ToolTip components are good examples.  You can also build that capability into your own control.  They typically work to add properties to certain control Types vs child controls. (Its a good question on how that control adds the properties only once something becomes a child of it...I'll have to think about that).  It may be added to eligible controls but not visible/active until it is a child control.

Comment: Cool, that's something new for me to research  and learn. Thanks @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the ProvideProperty attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx

In the following code u see how its used in the TableLayoutPanel

```
[ProvideProperty("ColumnSpan", typeof(Control))]
[ProvideProperty("RowSpan", typeof(Control))]
[ProvideProperty("Row", typeof(Control))] 
[ProvideProperty("Column", typeof(Control))]
[ProvideProperty("CellPosition", typeof(Control))] 
[DefaultProperty("ColumnCount")] 
[DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.TableLayoutPanelCodeDomSerializer, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign, "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign)]
[Docking(DockingBehavior.Never)] 
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.TableLayoutPanelDesigner, " + AssemblyRef.SystemDesign)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[SRDescription(SR.DescriptionTableLayoutPanel)] 
public class TableLayoutPanel : Panel, IExtenderProvider {
```